# Getting error while trying to Pandas Concat 2 csv files with Duplicate Indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python. I'm trying to concat 2 csv files to find out the differences. I'm using **Id** column as **index** to concatenate the values. Since the Csv files has **duplicate IDs** I'm getting the below error:
**ValueError**: Shape of passed values is (17, 4), indices imply (13, 4)

The error is on the line:

```
df_all_changes = pd.concat([old, new],axis=1,keys=['src','tgt'], join='inner')
```

Q1: How to handle/remedy the above error? Can someone please help

Q2: **Also I want to know what the below line does**:

```
df_changed = df_all_changes.groupby(level=0, axis=0).apply(lambda frame: frame.apply(report_diff, axis=1))
```

Q3: what would happen if I give level=1, axis=1 in the above line?

```
 import pandas as pd

#list of key column(s)
key=['Id']

# Read in the two excel files and fill NA
old = pd.read_csv('Source.csv')
new = pd.read_csv('Target.csv')

#set index
old=old.set_index(key)
new=new.set_index(key)

#identify dropped rows and added (new) rows
dropped_rows = set(old.index) - set(new.index)
added_rows = set(new.index) - set(old.index)
#print(old.loc[dropped_rows])

#combine data
df_all_changes = pd.concat([old,new],axis=1,keys=['src','tgt'],join='inner')
print(df_all_changes)

#swap column indexes
df_all_changes = df_all_changes.swaplevel(axis='columns')#[new.columns[0:]]


#prepare functio for comparing old values and new values
def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} ---> {}'.format(*x)

#apply the report_diff function
df_changed = df_all_changes.groupby(level=0, axis=0).apply(lambda frame: frame.apply(report_diff, axis=1))
print(df_changed)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You may want to provide examples of what the dataframe looks like;**

**Q1** - because two dataframes **do not have the same number of rows**, instead of using `pd.concat`, it would suggest you use `pd.merge`:

```
df_all_changes pd.merge(new, old, on=['src', 'tgt'], how='inner')
```

**Q2**

- level=0 means that you want to group by first hierarchical index; and
- axis=0 means you want to split by row level (it is default setting)

you should look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). and .apply() simply applies your custom function where you comparing old and new values column-wise (axis=1).

**Q3** - mentioned above in Q2.

Comment: Hi, The code works if I have unique keys despite the number of rows are different. I did try merge before but using merge creates an issue in the line where I use Swaplevel 
I ll add the dataframes to my question
#swap column indexes
df_all_changes = df_all_changes.swaplevel(axis='columns')#[new.columns[0:]]

Comment: If i use merge and comment the Swaplevel line aforementioned it's throwing error in the line where i use Apply/Lambda